# Magento2: How to get current product parent category on product detail page?

Tags: magento2, product, category

I want to get the current product parent category on the product detail page in Magento2?

My Code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
$local='';
$intr='';
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
  $catid = $cat->getId();
  $parentid = $cat['parent_id'];
 $local=$parentid;
    }
?>
```

But I am not getting the value

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use below code :**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getParentCategory()->getName();
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> create custom block in your custom module
>
> **Vendor\Module\Block\Yourblock.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Yourblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;
    protected $_categoryModel;
    public $_categoryNames = array();

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryModel = $categoryModel;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentProduct() {

        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }


    protected function getCurrentProductCategories() {
        $currentProduct = $this->getCurrentProduct(); // Your current product object

        $categories = $currentProduct->getCategoryIds(); /*returns category ids array assigned to product*/
        foreach($categories as $category):
            $cat = $this->_categoryModel->load($category);
            $this->_categoryNames[] =  $cat->getName();
        endforeach;
        return $this->_categoryNames;
    }

}
```

> **Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\category_name.phtml**

```
<?php 
$currentCategories = $block->getCurrentProductCategories();

if ($currentCategories): 
foreach($currentCategories as $key => $categoryName):
?>

    <div class="your-html-data">
        <?php echo $categoryName; ?>
    </div>

<?php           
endforeach;
endif; 
?>
```

> **Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Yourblock" name="product_category_name" template="Vendor_Module::category_name.phtml" >
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

> I hope it will work for you.