# How to get product category Id on product detail page Magento 2?

Tags: category, catalog, category-products, magento2.3.2, product-detail-page

I have a product which have assigned into more than 5 categories. I want to show the category detail of that product on product detail page. But which category detail I need to show?

I want to show the category name of that category from where the user coming.

Can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301792/magento2-how-to-get-current-product-parent-category-on-product-detail-page. your question answer is available here.

Comment: Check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/301856/59677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have created a module to show a current category on the product page. Check below files

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/currentCategory.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Module
 */
?>
<div class="category-name">
    <?php if($block->getCurrentCategory()): ?>
        <h3><?= __('Category') ?>: <?= $block->getCurrentCategory()->getName();; ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Module" name="current.category.on.product" template="Vendor_Module::currentCategory.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Check the below screenshot:
[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @kishor. I think this is working.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if its helpfull to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the current product category id then use below code

**NOTE: Please do not use the Object manager**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View')->getProduct();
$categoryId = $product->getCategoryId();
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
echo $cat->getName();
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($category->getData());*/
?>
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: Why you added the note to not use the Object manager while your solution is using it?